# In Java, trying to print how many digits in an integer evenly divide into the whole integer

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, integer, modulo

I'm trying to print how many digits in an integer evenly divide into the whole integer.

Using mod 10, I get the last digit of the integer, then do division by 10 to remove the last digit, and finally mod integer by each last digit to check if each digit is divisible into the whole integer. For some reason I'm getting an error (https://repl.it/CWWV/15).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int singleD, n1;
    int counter = 0;
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n = in.nextInt();
        n1 = n;
        while (n1 > 0){
            singleD = n1%10;
            n1 /= 10;  
            if(singleD != 0 && n%singleD == 0){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter = 0;
    }

}
```

Edit: it now works.

Comment: By the way: your program works perfectly fine. Yeah; on the site you linked I also get a strange error message. That's definitely a bug of this site - and not of your program. Because that works just fine. I would really recommend you to use an offline IDE like eclipse instead.

Comment: @AnnoSiedler I suggest you see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37506571/revisions); OP has incorporated my answer to fix the posted code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, I added testing for division by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) and then convert that to a character array. Next, I would use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate each character and parse it back to a digit for testing if the remainder<sup>**1**</sup> is `0` from division with the original `int` and if so increment a counter. Finally, display the count. Something like,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int counter = 0;
int t = in.nextInt();
for (char ch : String.valueOf(t).toCharArray()) {
    if (ch != '0' && t % Character.digit(ch, 10) == 0) {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("count = " + counter);
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Remembering to test for `0` to prevent division by `0`.</sub></sup>